What's the name for an anti-paradox?
For example, take Russell's Paradox (does the set of all sets that do not contain themselves contain itself?). This is a paradox because answering the question with "yes" makes the answer "no" and answering "no" makes the answer yes.
Let's change the statement to does the set of all sets that contain themselves contain itself? In this case, if we decide that it does, it does, and if we decide that it doesn't, it doesn't.
This is different to most mathematical statements where we can verify the truthfulness of a statement without having to make any choices. This one requires a choice to decide which outcome is true, although the statement is true regardless. Is there a name for this sort of phenomena?

Clearly related to your question are Henkin statements—see this answer for a thorough description.

self-reference ?

So Russell's paradox tells us that we have to be careful about what we mean when making this kind of statement. You are forgetting that: you talk about the *set of all sets that contain themselves", but that requires you to be working in a system of set theory that makes sense of such a set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinomy

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271563/does-the-set-of-all-sets-that-contain-themselves-contain-itself#:~:text=In%20ZF(C)%20it%20is,is%20not%20such%20a%20set.

Interestingly, the set you describe (under reasonable-and-nontrivializing hypotheses) can be shown to have to contain itself; the expected duality between it and Russell's paradox breaks down! See this old question of mine. (@Gonçalo also.)

@RobArthan Sort of. To be fair, the question is clear in the opening (where Russell's paradox is phrased as "does the set of all sets that do not contain themselves contain itself?"). Personally, my favored standard would be "contains" for "$\ni$" and "subsumes" for "$\supseteq$," but let's not go there.

In philosophy, there are some papers, which call statements like these "hypodoxes". The current research is still in a stage of finding a suitable definition of the concept of a hypodox.
Whereas it is fairly clear what is a paradoxical entity in the context of mathematics, it is not as clear what should be a hypodoxical entity in mathematics. As was hinted in the comments, there are many mathematical determinants of the (non-)self-membership of the co-Russel's set in various theories.
An interesting property of the co-Russel's set is that it cannot be that in the same model you have the co-Russell's set that would belong to itself and the co-Russell's that would not belong to itself. They would be same by the axiom of extensionality, but different by the axioms for equality. Funnily enough, it is derivable through the so-called Fixed Point Theorem of Naive Set Theory that both versions of the co-Russell's set exist, which yields a contradiction. I call it co-Russell's paradox.
I'm finishing a small paper on this topic, it should be on arxiv in coming days/weeks.

I'd be really interested to see the paper when it's out, could you send a link here when it is?

@Elliott sure can do

@Elliott hi, I uploaded a version here https://arxiv.org/abs/2411.11432 . I will replace it with a better version eventually.
